# Hibernate can not login to MySQL - Password verification failed

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have Hibernate 5.4.17 Final and MySQL 8.0 and hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pia?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">********</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.Korisnik"/>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.Kategorija"/>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.Obavestenje"/>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.Predmet"/>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.Materijal"/>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.Publikacija"/>
    <mapping class="rs.ac.bg.etf.dao.beans.PlanAngazovanja"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I test the password in MySQL Workbench connection is successful.

I don't know why I get the error `java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

Comment: Is mysql running locally? On what OS? Most new versions of mysql use the OS to authenticate the root account (the password is ignored).

Comment: MySQL works localy, on Windows 10. I'm using Eclipse. Thanks.